# How to change FloatingActionButton between Tabs?

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I'm trying to implement  ***FloatingActionButton***
from  ***Google Design Support Library*** into two of three tabs, and according to the [Material Design Guidelines - FloatingActionButton](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-floating-action-button)
it says:

> If there is a floating action button on multiple lateral screens (such
>   as on tabs), upon entering each screen, the button should show and
>   hide if the action contained on each is different. If the action is
>   the same, the button should stay on screen (and translate to a new
>   position, if necessary.)

[image: Example of FAB animation in tabs]

How can I make this kind of transition or animation for the FAB buttons in my app?

Comment: Do you have the XML code for it?

Comment: but still your action on the `fab.setOnclick.....` is still the same as  -- to enable different actions as that is why your changing it in the same place , store the `int position ` update it between `tablayout.OnPageChnge ... ` so on tab 1 `position = 1` and in your fab onclick ` switch (poistion) : `

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This functionality is not currently built into the FloatingActionButton so you'll have to animate it yourself. Assuming your FloatingActionButton is in your main activity, add the following function to your activity.

```
int[] colorIntArray = {R.color.walking,R.color.running,R.color.biking,R.color.paddling,R.color.golfing};
int[] iconIntArray = {R.drawable.ic_walk_white,R.drawable.ic_run_white,R.drawable.ic_bike_white,R.drawable.ic_add_white,R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white};

protected void animateFab(final int position) {
    fab.clearAnimation();
    // Scale down animation
    ScaleAnimation shrink =  new ScaleAnimation(1f, 0.2f, 1f, 0.2f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    shrink.setDuration(150);     // animation duration in milliseconds
    shrink.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    shrink.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // Change FAB color and icon
            fab.setBackgroundTintList(getResources().getColorStateList(colorIntArray[position]));
            fab.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(iconIntArray[position], null));

            // Scale up animation
            ScaleAnimation expand =  new ScaleAnimation(0.2f, 1f, 0.2f, 1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            expand.setDuration(100);     // animation duration in milliseconds
            expand.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
            fab.startAnimation(expand);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    fab.startAnimation(shrink);
}
```

Update the color and drawable resources to match your project. Add a tab selection listener in your onCreate method and call the animate function when a tab is selected.

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        animateFab(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
});
```

Make sure you have enough colors and icons to match the number of tabs you have.

Comment: This worked for me. But how can i hide the FAB for specific tab? lets say at `[position=2]` i don't want to show any fab?

Comment: @bernzkie I think you can a if iconIntArray[position]!=0 run everything in animationEnd, so that the expand animation will never get called to achieve that

Answer (score 24):

Below is the simple way to achieve your desired result

[image]

Add two (or equivalent to your tab actions) `FloatingActionButton` in your main activity like below

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabChat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_fab_chat" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabPerson"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_fab_person"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Now in your MainActivity.java use Fab's default functions to hide and show on each tab selection like below

```
private void animateFab(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fabChat.show();
            fabPerson.hide();
            break;
        case 1:
            fabPerson.show();
            fabChat.hide();
            break;

        default:
            fabChat.show();
            fabPerson.hide();
            break;
    }
}
```

Call `animateFab` function as below

```
TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener onTabSelectedListener = new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        animateFab(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
};

ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener onPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        animateFab(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
};
```

Comment: That's really very simple because show() and hide() already implement an animation. But unfortunately, the show() of the new fabs starts before the hide() of the old fab has finished. Is it possible to call show() when the hide() animation has completed? Maybe with a listener?

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 4):

Extending blackcj's Answer, The solution worked really good as explained. However I would like to add something in that.

I have watched that video in slow motion. The drawable and fab are animating differently. When hiding, fab and drawable are in sync. While showing, fab is coming back first, and after 60-70 percent completion the drawable start animation from 0 and rotating and scaling coming to full size.

However, I was not able to achieve drawable animating saperatly. But, I managed to rotate and scale with different Interpolators and slightly modified time. So it seems more like in the video which is also presented in google design guidelines.

```
int[] colorIntArray = {R.color.red,R.color.gray,R.color.black};
int[] iconIntArray = {R.drawable.ic_btn1, R.drawable.ic_btn2, R.drawable.ic_btn3};

    protected void animateFab(final int position) {
        fab.clearAnimation();

        // Scale down animation
        ScaleAnimation shrink = new ScaleAnimation(1f, 0.1f, 1f, 0.1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        shrink.setDuration(100);     // animation duration in milliseconds
        shrink.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        shrink.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                // Change FAB color and icon
                fab.setBackgroundTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(), colorIntArray[position]));
                fab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), iconIntArray[position]));

                // Rotate Animation
                Animation rotate = new RotateAnimation(60.0f, 0.0f,
                        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                        0.5f);
                rotate.setDuration(150);
                rotate.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

                // Scale up animation
                ScaleAnimation expand = new ScaleAnimation(0.1f, 1f, 0.1f, 1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
                expand.setDuration(150);     // animation duration in milliseconds
                expand.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

                // Add both animations to animation state
                AnimationSet s = new AnimationSet(false); //false means don't share interpolators
                s.addAnimation(rotate);
                s.addAnimation(expand);
                fab.startAnimation(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
        fab.startAnimation(shrink);
    }
```

And tab tab change listener as usual:

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        animateFab(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Expanding upon blackcj's & kirtan403's answers, I have also added the ability to hide the `fab` on a chosen tab (in this case the 1st tab), which answer's bernzkie's question under blackcj's answer.

To achieve this I first declared `int[]`'s with 3 items, each for the `fab` of each of the 3 tabs. I set the first item in each to 0 because that will be the 1st tab's invisible `fab` that doesn't need resources.

```
int[] colorIntArray = {0, R.color.fab_red, R.color.fab_green};
int[] iconIntArray = {0, R.drawable.fab_pencil, R.drawable.fab_chevron};
```

I then set an `if` statement in the `onCreate` method of the `Activity` that features the `fab` and tabs. This statement hides the fab and scales it down, so that when it is made visible again, it can be made to only scale up, not down unnecessarily, then up again. I set the scale to match final scale of blackcj's scale down animation.

```
    if (tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition() == 0) {
        // if on the 1st tab
        fab.hide();
        // scale down to only scale up when switching from 1st tab
        fab.setScaleX(0.2f);
        fab.setScaleY(0.2f);
    }
```

Then outside the `onCreate` method, I added blackcj's `animateFab` method, with kirtan403's `rotate` modification. However, I modified the `animateFab` method to also have a conditional statement, where:

- if it returns to the 1st tab, the `fab` is hidden (it scales down automatically when hiding);
- when switching from a tab where the fab is already full size and visible to another tab where it is meant to be visible, it performs the full scale down, change & scale up animation;
- when switching **from** the tab with the hidden `fab` (in this case the 1st tab), the `fab` is made visible, then scaled up (not scaled down, then scaled up) with the custom animation.

  ```
  protected void animateFab(final int position) {
      fab.clearAnimation();
      if (tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition() == 0) {
          // if on the 1st tab
          fab.hide();
      } else if (fab.getScaleX() == 1f) {
          // if the fab is full scale
          // Scale down animation
          ScaleAnimation shrink =  new ScaleAnimation(1f, 0.2f, 1f, 0.2f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
          shrink.setDuration(150);     // animation duration in milliseconds
          shrink.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
          shrink.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
              @Override
              public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

              }

              @Override
              public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                  // Change FAB color and icon
                  fab.setBackgroundTintList(getResources().getColorStateList(colorIntArray[position]));
                  fab.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(iconIntArray[position], null));

                  // Scale up animation
                  ScaleAnimation expand = new ScaleAnimation(0.2f, 1f, 0.2f, 1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
                  expand.setDuration(100);     // animation duration in milliseconds
                  expand.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

                  // Rotate Animation
                  Animation rotate = new RotateAnimation(60.0f, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
                  rotate.setDuration(200);
                  rotate.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

                  // Add both animations to animation state
                  AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(false); //false means don't share interpolators
                  animationSet.addAnimation(expand);
                  animationSet.addAnimation(rotate);
                  fab.startAnimation(animationSet);
              }

              @Override
              public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

              }
          });
          fab.startAnimation(shrink);
      } else {
          // if the fab is already scaled down
          // Change FAB color and icon
          fab.setBackgroundTintList(getResources().getColorStateList(colorIntArray[position]));
          fab.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(iconIntArray[position], null));
          fab.show();

          // Scale up animation
          ScaleAnimation expand = new ScaleAnimation(0.2f, 1f, 0.2f, 1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
          expand.setDuration(100);     // animation duration in milliseconds
          expand.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

          // Rotate Animation
          Animation rotate = new RotateAnimation(60.0f, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
          rotate.setDuration(200);
          rotate.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

          // Add both animations to animation state
          AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(false); //false means don't share interpolators
          animationSet.addAnimation(expand);
          animationSet.addAnimation(rotate);
          fab.startAnimation(animationSet);
      }

  }
  ```

Then I just added blackcj's unchanged tab selection listener to the `onCreate` method.

```
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            animateFab(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

Hope this helps, it certainly works flawlessly for me. Thanks to blackcj & kirtan403. :)

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I've found a solution that's pretty easy and shows an animation that's exactly like the attached gif – in @Nauman's oder @Omid's solutions, the show animation starts before the hide animation has finished. But be sure to use the newest Support Library! I've tested it with version 23.2.1.

Use case:

- Show fab 1 on tab 1 (index 0)
- Show fab 2 on tab 2 (index 1)
- Don't show any fab on tab 3 (index 2)

In your xml, place to fabs with unique id's and visibility set to invisible:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/some_icon"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/another_icon"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Then, add two fields for your fabs to your Activity (you can also use local variables or get the View each time by `findViewById(...)`):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FloatingActionButton fab1;
    private FloatingActionButton fab2;
```

In your `onCreate(...)` function, find these views and save them into the declared fields:

```
fab1 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab1);
fab2 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab2);
```

Next declare a function that shows the right fab for the given position. The default case (tab 3 or more) is quite easy: Just call the `hide()` method on the fabs. `show()` and `hide()` already implement a scaling animation. But if we hide fab2 on tab 1, we have to wait until it has finished before we can show fab1. So set an `FloatingActionButton.OnVisibilityChangedListener` as parameter for the `hide(...)` method and show the desired new fab in the `onHidden(...)` method of that listener. The result is this:

```
public void showRightFab(int tab) {
    switch (tab) {
        case 0:
            fab2.hide(new FloatingActionButton.OnVisibilityChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onHidden(FloatingActionButton fab) {
                    fab1.show();
                }
            });
            break;

        case 1:
            fab1.hide(new FloatingActionButton.OnVisibilityChangedListener() [
                @Override
                public void onHidden(FloatingActionButton fab) {
                    fab2.show();
                }
            });
            break;

        default:
            fab1.hide();
            fab2.hide();
            break;
    }
}
```

That was the most difficult part! Now add a listener to the ViewPager to call the `showRightFab(...)` function each time the selected tab changes.

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        showRightFab(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
});
```

At last, call the function one time manually in the `onCreate(...)` method to show the fab at the default tab, because the `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`'s `onPageSelected(...)` method isn't called on startup (e. g. otherwise if you open the app and it shows tab 1, no fab will be shown because the `showRightFab(...)` function has never been called).

```
showRightFab(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
```

That work's perfectly in my application!

Answer (score 1):

you can add a listener to viewpager and show and hide fab according to its state
when you start scrolling the viewpager this is the order of states SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING  SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING SCROLL_STATE_IDLE

for example:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        if(state==ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
            fab.show();
        else if(state==ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING)
            fab.hide();

    }
```

Comment: Your idea is good, but it is bit late animation after tabs changed. I also tried with other state but no luck!

Answer (score 0):

That's what worked for me:

```
private boolean isFloatingActionButtonHidden = false;
private int[] colorIntArray = {R.color.walking,R.color.running,R.color.biking,R.color.paddling,R.color.golfing};
private int[] iconIntArray = {R.drawable.ic_walk_white,R.drawable.ic_run_white,R.drawable.ic_bike_white,R.drawable.ic_add_white,R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white};

viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        switch (state) {
            case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING:
                // This is triggered just before the view pager reaches the final state
                // if you want to trigger the animation after the page reaches its final position
                // just move this to "case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:"
                showFloatingActionButton(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
                break;
            case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
                // This is only triggered if user pulls to the left of the start or right of the end
                if (isFloatingActionButtonHidden) {
                    showFloatingActionButton(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
                }
                break;
            default:
                // in all other cases just hide the fab if it is not visable
                if (!isFloatingActionButtonHidden) {
                    hideFloatingActionButton();
                }
        }
   }
});

private void showFloatingActionButton(int position) {
    fab.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(iconIntArray[position], null));

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        floatingActionButton.setBackgroundTintList(getResources().getColorStateList(iconIntArray[position], getTheme()));
    } else {
        floatingActionButton.setBackgroundTintList(getResources().getColorStateList(iconIntArray[position]));
    }

    floatingActionButton.show();
}

private void hideFloatingActionButton() {
    isFloatingActionButtonHidden = true;
    floatingActionButton.hide();
}
```