# Change FloatingActionButton from a Fragment in a Tabbed Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, floating-action-button

How are you ? 
I am new in android programming. I am facing an issue that I have tried to handle. But, I couldn't. 
I have created a new project. Tabbed Activity.

I have changed some of it's settings. 
For each tab, I create a fragment.
I kept the default floatingActionButton in the MainActity Layout. 
I tried to access it from a fragment.

An error arises.
Here are my MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.Main_FAB);

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));


}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0 : Summary summary = new Summary(); return summary ;
            case 1 : Expense_items expenseItems = new Expense_items(); return expenseItems;
            case 2 : Linage_items linage_items= new Linage_items(); return linage_items;
            default: return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }
}
}
```

my Summary fragment as the followings:

```
public class Summary extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_summary, container, false);
    TextView summary_text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.summary_text);
    summary_text.setText("You are in Summary Fragment Fragment");
    FloatingActionButton myFB  = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);

    return rootView;
}
}
```

In my MainActivity layout I created the floatingActionButton as the followings:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/Main_FAB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

The reason I don't want to create a FloatingActionButton in my Fragments is because I don't want to change the location of it in the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle the floating button in the MainActiviy that is handling all of your fragments. 
Try to do this in your MainActity:

```
         myFab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.Main_FAB);
    myFab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), iconIntArray[0]));

    myFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int position = tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition();

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    myFab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, iconIntArray[0]));

                    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                            EnterExpensesActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("USER_ID",USER_ID);
                    intent.putExtra("FRAGMENT",0);

                    intent.putExtra("TITLE",getResources().getString(R.string.Enter_Expense_title));
                    intent.putExtra("FILED",getResources().getString(R.string.Enter_Expense_text));
                    startActivity(intent);

                    break;
                case 1:
                    myFab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, iconIntArray[position]));
                    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                            Enter_E_L_Items.class);
                    intent.putExtra("USER_ID",USER_ID);
                    intent.putExtra("FRAGMENT",0);

                    intent.putExtra("TITLE",getResources().getString(R.string.Enter_Expense_title));
                    intent.putExtra("FILED",getResources().getString(R.string.Enter_Expense_text));

                    startActivity(intent);
                    /*
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Expenses ", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();*/
                break;
                case 2:
                    myFab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, iconIntArray[position]));
                    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                            Enter_E_L_Items.class);
                    intent.putExtra("USER_ID",USER_ID);
                    intent.putExtra("FRAGMENT",1);
                    intent.putExtra("TITLE",getResources().getString(R.string.Enter_Liange_title));
                    intent.putExtra("FILED",getResources().getString(R.string.Enter_Linage_text));

                    startActivity(intent);
                    /*
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Linage ", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();*/
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

I am assuming that you are using the default Tab Activity

You can change and set animation to the floating button as:

```
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewpager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            animateFab(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
    setupTabIcons();

}
```

I have created the animateFab method as the followings:

```
    protected void animateFab(final int position) {
    final FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.Main_FAB);
    fab.clearAnimation();

    // Scale down animation
    ScaleAnimation shrink = new ScaleAnimation(1f, 0.1f, 1f, 0.1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    shrink.setDuration(100);     // animation duration in milliseconds
    shrink.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    shrink.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // Change FAB color and icon
            fab.setBackgroundTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(), colorIntArray[position]));
            fab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), iconIntArray[position]));

            // Rotate Animation
            Animation rotate = new RotateAnimation(60.0f, 0.0f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                    0.5f);
            rotate.setDuration(150);
            rotate.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

            // Scale up animation
            ScaleAnimation expand = new ScaleAnimation(0.1f, 1f, 0.1f, 1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            expand.setDuration(150);     // animation duration in milliseconds
            expand.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

            // Add both animations to animation state
            AnimationSet s = new AnimationSet(false); //false means don't share interpolators
            s.addAnimation(rotate);
            s.addAnimation(expand);
            fab.startAnimation(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    fab.startAnimation(shrink);
}
```

Comment: what is Method .setImageDrawable

Comment: This method is supposed to change the icon of the floating button. 
You can implement as I have if you want. I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

from fragment you may access the MainActivity by

```
(MainActivity) getActivity()
```

within the MainActivity you may create a function like

```
public void actionA()
```

and call it from fragment A by

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).actionA()
```

actionB from fragmentB etc..

Answer (score 0):

First of all I can see that in your MainActivity's XML file your fab's id is 'Main_FAB'
not 'fab' as you writed here

```
    FloatingActionButton myFB  = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
```

Also , your fab is in activity not in fragment so to access it you'll need to override in your
fragment class the  **onActivityCreated** method and here you can take an instance of your FloatingActionButton.

This is an example that it should work for you.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
myFab = (FloatingActionButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Main_FAB);
}
```

Comment: My Tabbed Activity has three fragments. I copied your code in every fragment. I created an Onclick Listener inside onActivityCreated. When I am in fragment 1 the text of frag 2 appears. When I am in 2 the text of frag 1 appears. and so, 
what wrong have I done ?

Comment: I don't know how I could help you since I'm not sure what is the result you want to achieve with this tabbed activity and fab, so please,firstly, let me know this.

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply. I have 3 tabs. For each tab I want to control the floating button individually. So, Each tab is built on a fragment. I want to handle the floating Button fully. For example. in Tab 1: the FloatingButton background image is "call". The Action is to go to phone Dial. Tab 2. The Background image is "msg". The action is to go to Messages. And so on. 
I hope I made it clear.

Comment: So you want a different behaviour for fab on each of your fragment.

Comment: This is exactly what I want

Comment: I don't think this is possible using a single floating action button. Either you put 3 floating action buttons on main activity and change visibility and on click listener according to the selected tab ( check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415742/how-to-change-floatingactionbutton-between-tabs))  , or you can have a different fab in each of your tab fragments . I think the first approach is more used .